# There is a difference between Date and Calendar when mapping dates on JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, date, jpa, calendar

I'm started on a new project where the dates on JPA entities are saved using the `java.util.Calendar` class, like:

```
@Column(name="order_date", nullable=false)
private Calendar orderDate;
```

I always¹ used `java.util.Date` class to save dates using JPA/Hibernate:

```
@Column(name="order_date", nullable=false)
private Date orderDate;
```

So, there is some difference between `Calendar` and `Date` that I need to be aware when using JPA/Hibernate?

<sup>1. I'm using an old version of Hibernate, so I can't use the `LocalDate`/`LocalDateTime` classes.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The difference between Date and Calendar is that Date class operates with specific instant in time and Calendar class gives you possibility for converting between a specific instant in time and a set of calendar fields such as HOUR , YEAR , MONTH , DAY_OF_MONTH.

You can use both, Date or Calendar. But Calendar class provide you more functions and reliability to use and you can extract the Date object by using **getTime()** method of Calendar class.